# Ошибка в TypeScript. Argument of type 'TypePizzaItem' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

Начал задавать конкретные типы в тех местах где ставил any. При компиляции выводится следующая ошибка:

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

const showModalConstructor = (item: TypePizzaItem) => {
        dispatch(openModalItemConstructor(item));
        return;
    }
```

[image: 1]

action:

```
export const openModalItemConstructor = createAction('OPEN_MODAL_ITEM');
```

Тип:

```
export type TypePizzaItem = {
    id: number, 
    title: string,
    description: string,
    price: number,
    img: {
        traditional: {
            medium: string,
            big: string
        }
    },
    volume: string | null,
    volumes?: {
        traditional: string[],
        thin: string[]
    },
    quantity?: number,
}
```

Dispatch доставал с помощью хука, описанного в документации:

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from '../store/store'

// Используйте во всем приложении вместо обычных `useDispatch` и `useSelector`
type DispatchFunc = () => AppDispatch
export const useAppDispatch: DispatchFunc = useDispatch
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

Не могу понять, почему возникает эта проблема и что нужно поменять в коде?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тут не хватает указания типа:

```
export const openModalItemConstructor = createAction<TypePizzaItem>('OPEN_MODAL_ITEM');
```

Comment: Попробовал, появилась теперь такая ошибка: TS2349: This expression is not callable. Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures. Подчеркивает красным action

Comment: Когда импортирую тип в actions: import { TypePizzaItem } from "../types/types"; То появляется следующая ошибка  ERROR in ./src/actions/actions.js 8:55-68
[0] export 'TypePizzaItem' (imported as 'TypePizzaItem') was not found in '../types/types' (module has no exports) Может неправильный импорт?

Comment: скорее всего, мне к сожалению не видно расположение файлов

Comment: предположу что путь ../../types/types должен быть

Comment: Разобрался, не заметил что формат файла стоит js а не ts у actions, отсюда и тип как-таковой не назначался, отсюда и полезли эти ошибки. Благодарю, первый данный ответ был верным.